# What size cake pan could be substitued in place of muffins?

Tags: baking, cake, muffins

I have a recipe that the blogger said made 24 mini muffins and had enough batter left for 4 regular sized muffins.  If I want to make it into a cake or loaf, what size pan would I need?  I know it would need to have the baking times adjusted.  The recipe, below, is topped with a streusel topping.

1 1/2 cups all-purpose flour

1 teaspoon baking soda

1 teaspoon baking powder

1/2 teaspoon salt

1/2 teaspoon cinnamon

3  mashed ripe bananas

3/4 cup white sugar

1 egg

1/3 cup melted butter

Comment: Looks like a nice [Fermi problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem)! :D Can you tell me what the diameter of a mini muffin and a regular muffin are? It'll try to do some math :D

Comment: Here's what I've found (I'm not home so I can't actually measure the different cups):  
Standard muffin cup is about 2 1/2 inches in diameter and holds 1/4 to 1/3 cup batter. 
Miniature muffin cup is about 1 1/2 to 2 inches in diameter and holds 1/8 cup or 2 tablespoons batter.

Comment: Baking time: Somewhere between 25 min (muffins) and 60 minutes ([Gugelhupf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugelhupf)). I would decrease the temperature (maybe ~10°C?) to prevent burning before the cake is done.

Comment: Since it has a streusel topping, I would probably do an 8X8 or 9X13 pan.  I just don't know which one would be better for the amount of batter I will have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Which pan should I use?

**Volume of a regular muffins**
1/3 cup equals about 79 ml
1/4 cup equals about 60 ml
--> I take the average of both: 70ml per regular muffin

**Volume of mini muffins**
1/8 cup equals about 30 ml
2 tablespoons equal about 20 ml
--> I take the average of both: 25ml per mini muffin

**Total volume** 
24 mini muffins ⋅ 25 ml/mini muffin + 4 ⋅ 70 ml/regular muffin = 880 ml = 880 cm³ batter

**Using the 8x8 pan** 
8" ⋅ 8" = 20.32 cm ⋅ 20.32 cm ≈ 413 cm². Height of the unbaked cake: 880 cm³ / 413 cm² ≈ 2 cm ≈ 0,75".

**Using the 9x13 pan** 
9" ⋅ 13" = 22.86 cm ⋅ 33.02 cm ≈ 755 cm². Height of the unbaked cake: 800 cm³ / 755 cm² ≈ 1 cm ≈ 0,4 inches.

I assume that baked muffins will gain the same the volume as the volume of the unbaked batter. Or at least 3/4 of their original volume.

[image]
[image]

The cake **without streusel topping** in the **8" x 8" pan** will be **4 cm or 1,5"** thick and the cake in the **9" x 13" pan** will be **2 cm or 0,8"** thick *on the average*. After baking, the cake in the 8" x 8" pan might look like a [molehill cake](http://www.chefkoch.de/rs/s0/maulwurfkuchen/Rezepte.html) :D

After adding streusel topping, I assume you cake will be 1 cm thicker. To prevent extreme doming and to have a shorter baking time I recommend using the 9" x 13" pan.

## Baking time

Some receipes in my cook / baking book say that pound cakes backed directly on a sheet pan take about 25 to 30 minutes at 180°C / 356F (in an electric oven) to de done. You should still check your cake continuously after 15 minutes.

---

image sources:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Muffins_with_honey.jpg
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Muffin_Starbucks_2.jpg

Comment: I was just doing the math based on what I found earlier (volume) and what I found at http://thebakingpan.com/baking-pan-sizes/.  I think you're right.  The 8X8 is just too small.  A 9X9 would be better, but since I don't have one, the 9X13 seems to be my best option.  The streusel seems to be what's driving the larger pan.  (Oh, and thanks for making me want blueberry muffins now!  :D)

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a fairly standard banana bread recipe that you have been baking as muffins. Based on the amounts of your ingredients, this should bake-up just fine in a 9" x 5" loaf pan.  At 350° F, on the lower-middle baking rack, a loaf should finish baking somewhere in the 40-45 minute range.  Baked as a loaf, test for doneness early and often - a thin knife inserted into the center of the loaf should come out clean when the loaf is done - if the knife shows signs of uncooked batter, keep baking until it comes out clean.  If you prefer to use an instant read thermometer to test for doneness, shoot for about 190°F.  Be sure to cool the loaf for a good 2 hours before slicing.